# Predicting future enrollment

Tags: r, supervised-learning

I have data concerning registrations of students in courses similar to

```
qrDate  discipline  number  remaining   registered  session year
17/06/2007  COSC    111 57  43  1   2007
17/06/2007  COSC    121 26  34  2   2007
17/06/2007  COSC    122 35  5   1   2007
17/06/2007  COSC    150 36  4   1   2007
17/06/2007  COSC    211 40  0   2   2007
```

The full dataset is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kot9c707vzt394/enrol_data.csv?dl=0

I'd like to know if there are any methods I can use to predict future student enrollment, or more interestingly, if I can project future student survival (see how many students will drop out by the end of the semester, compared to from the beginning) rates.

**qrDate:** date that a script was run to scrape the data
**discipline:** course code (Computer Science is in the above)
**number:** course number
**remaining:** remaining seats in the course (seats left over)
**registered:** registered seats in the course (seats taken)
**session:** semester
**year:** year

Especially methods that are available via a package in R.

Thank you!

Comment: I googled "survival analysis in R" and "forecasting in R" and some really great material came up, including the `survival` package and the `forecast` package.